# Define selective blocking of upstream/downstream jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a setup of multiple jobs with automated triggering between them.

All of the jobs have both '*Block build when upstream project is building*' and '*Block build when downstream project is building*' set to true. It worked fine until the need for additional job for upload the other jobs' artifacts appeared.

It is a lengthy process which I don't want to block the whole building pipeline. So I separated it as a job. It is triggered by all other jobs and pushes artifacts to a remote server with low-bandwidth connection.

But they still wait due to the settings mentioned.

Is there a way to make them not wait for this particular job? Maybe the approach is wrong and it should not be a downstream job for them? If not - how to monitor other jobs executions and gather the results easily? Maybe there is some non-blocking alternative for ArtifactDeployer, that just sets the task and finishes - I don't need to collect the results of the upload job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It was just before my eyes...

I missed very important part of Parametrized Trigger Plugin: If you use it as a build step and not post-build action it can either wait or not wait for result of downstream job. Downstream appears as '(non-blocking)' subproject of the upstream job.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Jenkins Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin), which allows you to orchestrate complex workflows using a concise DSL - I find this a lot easier to understand than having to look through the settings for multiple jobs.

Comment: Isn't it too much burden for simple fire'n'forget scenario? Additionally I don't want to invoke the whole process when something in the middle changes.